# System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure when Calling WCF Services throwing exception in mono android application

Tags: android, .net, wcf, mono, xamarin.android

I am working on Mono Android Mobile applicaiton. I am calling my WCF Services in my applicaiton, I added wcf services using  ->Add WebRefernce option of Project Menu.  My Problem is I am getting exception when i am running the calling the wcf services on the device.

***Exception***:

> {System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00000] in
>   :0     at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke
>   (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in
>   :0 }

My device has internet connection using WiFi connection to get and post data

and another way

I tried calling the services using the net connection using Mobile Data i.e with the Mobile NetWork Provider's internet connection.. This time i am getting a different exception..

> {System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404:
>   NotFound   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReceiveResponse
>   (System.Net.WebResponse response,
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage message,
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension[] extensions) [0x00000] in
>   :0     at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke
>   (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in
>   :0     at
>   AndroidWCFExample.WirelessService.SAGServer.ProcessSomeUpdate
>   (AndroidWCFExample.WirelessService.WebServicesClient oClientInfo,
>   System.String ParameterInfo) [0x00001] in C:\Some Dotnet
>   Examples\AndroidWCFExample\AndroidWCFExample\Web
>   References\WirelessService\Reference.cs:1232    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   AndroidWCFExample.WirelessService.SAGServer:ProcessSomeUpdate
>   (AndroidWCFExample.WirelessService.WebServicesClient,string)   at
>   AndroidWCFExample.EmployeeInfoActivity.button_Click (System.Object
>   sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0007a] in C:\Some Dotnet
>   Examples\AndroidWCFExample\AndroidWCFExample\EmployeeInfoActivity.cs:79
>   }

I am searching for solution to fix this, but not getting correct answer. 
So Please let me know what i need to do, to get it fixed. Please help me out.

This is working Correctly when i run application on android emulator

Thanks in Advance..
Sreeni

Comment: How do you expect to help you without the code?

Answer (score 3):

Setting Internet permission to your app and make sure that your device connected with Internet.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but was facing the same error, so thought to share the solution.

1. The best solution I found, when that exception occurs while the Wifi
   is connected, is just to retry my server call with a slight sleep in
   between. It works most of the time, otherwise if the second call
   fails I cancel the request.
2. This error can also raise if the user's Wifi is very unstable or the
   signal is very low. The same error occurs if there is no internet
   connection at all, even if connected to Wifi.