# Is Newtonsoft.JSON supported for .net Framework 4.6 in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, .net, json, web-services, xamarin

I'm consuming WCF based web services for an android app. Previously the web application (for which webservices have been written) was using .NET framework 3.5, recently it was migrated to .net framework 4.6. The below pieces of code are throwing the exception :

> "Error: NameResolutionFailure   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse"

```
url = https://121.242.223.199/SEZOnlineWebService/SezOnlineWebService.svc/FetchNumberOfSEZandUnits/1

 private async Task<JsonValue> FetchErrAsync(string url)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";


            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {


                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {

                    JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));

                                        return jsonDoc;
                }
            }
            }
```

The webservices are up and running. Json format data is being displayed in a normal web browser, however from the android app, we are getting the above exception. 
Note: This code was working fine when the web application was running on .NET framework 3.5

Comment: It is you've to install it via nuget package

Comment: Yes I have installed newtonsoft.json through nuget package.

Comment: Be sure to have same order of object properties and case on both sides i.e your app and service

Comment: and to get object on your end 

var objectClassName = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonValue>(json);

Comment: here "json" is the string response revcieved

Comment: NameResolutionFailure has nothing to do with Json or alike. It simply says that it can not resolve the host name. So the question is: can you access the service from the browser installed on the Android device?

Comment: @Mohtisham I have used the same format for deserialization as you have suggested, but still no luck!

Comment: Yeah without any issue I've been using in mine xamarin.forms this  alot for webapi project to access the rest application by IP based url

Comment: please share all your code webrequest code. including objects on both side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `Newtonsoft.JSON` supported for .net Framework 4.6 in Xamarin.Android?

Yes it is supported for .net Framework 4.6 in Xamarin.Android.

You can convert your stream to string and then use `Newtonsoft.JSON` to convert the string to object.

> "Error: NameResolutionFailure at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse"

This error is not about the `Newtonsoft.JSON`, it is about the network environment. By testing your url . (https://121.242.223.199/SEZOnlineWebService/SezOnlineWebService.svc/FetchNumberOfSEZandUnits/1), I find the secure issue with certificate, I think you can try bypass certificate validation with the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, and try again.

**I have get your json string successfully by following code：**

```
 public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button bt1;
        TextView tv1;
        TextView tv2;
        TextView tv3;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            bt1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            tv1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            tv2 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            tv3 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            bt1.Click += Bt1_Click;
        }

        private async void Bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await FetchErrAsync("http://121.242.223.199/SEZOnlineWebService/SezOnlineWebService.svc/FetchNumberOfSEZandUnits/1");
        }
        public bool MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(System.Object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            bool isOk = true;
            // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
            if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < chain.ChainStatus.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (chain.ChainStatus[i].Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown)
                    {
                        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
                        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
                        chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                        chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;
                        bool chainIsValid = chain.Build((X509Certificate2)certificate);
                        if (!chainIsValid)
                        {
                            isOk = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return isOk;
        }
        private async Task FetchErrAsync(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback;
            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    //JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                    //return jsonDoc;
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    tv1.Text = text;
                    var myFetchNumberOfSEZandUnitsResultguage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyFetchNumberOfSEZandUnitsResultguage>(text);
                    tv2.Text = myFetchNumberOfSEZandUnitsResultguage.FetchNumberOfSEZandUnitsResult[0].Key;
                    tv3.Text = myFetchNumberOfSEZandUnitsResultguage.FetchNumberOfSEZandUnitsResult[0].Value;
                }
            }
        }


    }
    public class MyFetchNumberOfSEZandUnitsResultguage
    {
        public List<MyKeyValue> FetchNumberOfSEZandUnitsResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyKeyValue
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

screen shot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize your response to a specific object you could use:

```
NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(webResponseInString);
```

Also a big note: WCF isn't fully supported in the Xamarin stack, so be careful when using WCF.

Comment: I have used the same format for deserialization as you have suggested, but still no luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999616/httpwebrequest-nameresolutionfailure-exception-in-net-with-mono-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for sharing the post Mittchel, but we are not using host name for url, rather we are using the ip address directly. url= https://121.242.223.199/SEZOnlineWebService/SezOnlineWebService.svc/FetchNumberOfSEZandUnits/1

And this issue cannot be due to my internet connection, since the code is working fine if I use the old web services url (web application built on .net 3.5)